# Get the list of python standard library function names

Tags: python

I can get the list of python builtin functions by using `dir(__builtins__)`. 
I wonder if there is a way to get the list of function names for the python standard libraries including `append`, `Math.exp`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`append` is a method of class `list`, and accordingly you can get it from `dir(list)`.

Similarly, `math.exp` is a free function of module `math`, and `dir(math)` contains `exp` as expected.

Given that you want only methods/functions, and assuming you want to avoid non-public attributes, perhaps you could do something like this:

```
import math

def is_public(name):
    return not (name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__'))

def get_functions(source):
    return [name for name in dir(source) if callable(getattr(source, name)) and is_public(name)]

print(f'Methods of class list: {get_functions(list)}', end='\n\n')
print(f'Functions of module math: {get_functions(math)}')
```

Output:

```
Methods of class list: ['append', 'clear', 'copy', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']

Functions of module math: ['acos', 'acosh', 'asin', 'asinh', 'atan', 'atan2', 'atanh', 'ceil', 'copysign', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'erf', 'erfc', 'exp', 'expm1', 'fabs', 'factorial', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'fsum', 'gamma', 'gcd', 'hypot', 'isclose', 'isfinite', 'isinf', 'isnan', 'ldexp', 'lgamma', 'log', 'log10', 'log1p', 'log2', 'modf', 'pow', 'radians', 'remainder', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'trunc']
```

If you do want *all* attributes, you can remove the `is_public` condition.

Answer (score -1):

All functions for the standard object `list` can be obtained by:

```
dir(list)
```

(`dir(__builtins__)` to get a list of all objects)

To get a list of all imported modules:

```
help('modules')
```

Comment: The question is about getting a list of names of standard libraries. Not what methods the builtin `list` type has, nor what `dir(__builtins__)` gives you, nor what `help('module')` would give you (which would include all site packages and anything on the python path).